# VS too many ../../ in reference HintPath

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, reference, projects-and-solutions

My TFS folder structure has project files four layers deep as according to the example structure below. I reference a Dll that is located in the ThirdPartyLib folder and the file is automatically referenced as: ..........\SolutionHoldingFolder\DEV_Region\ThirdPartyLib\Referenced.dll. The problem is that each DEV_Region is mapped in TFS so each developer has a different folder name for the layer above the particular region. So this breaks the build in our automated build and on every other developer's machine.

The reference should not need to go up the file structure that much. The minimum amount and the path that does not break the automated and every other developer's build is: ......\ThirdPartyLib\Referenced.dll. This path is safe when promoted to the upper branches.

**How can I have Visual Studio reference file paths in the most minimal way by default instead of the way that will break merges and automated builds?**

Example structure:
SolutionHoldingFolder
    DEV_Region
        ThirdPartyLib
        SolutionFolder
            LayerFolder1
            LayerFolder2
                ProjectFolder
                    ProjectFile

I am using VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the .*proj files directly and remove the extra indirection (notepad or unload then edit the project).

Visual Studio is considering the position of the solution file as the base, so you can also use ancillary solution to avoid some levels.

Comment: Ive been fixing the files by editting the .proj files. I am looking for a solution so I dont have to manually do that. Also, The automatically created path goes two levels above where my solution file is, so Im not sure the solution file is considered the base in this situation.

Comment: I do not think there is a solution, what you can easily do is to code a script to check for the condition in proj files, add it to the CI build and educate developers on the issue.
A step forward is to script the edit of proj files.